# Need a dm cheat sheet

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques, online-resources

Basically, need some basic references. Three in fact. A dm screen/quick reference download, a npc/monster stat card, and a miniatures blank stat card.

I figure that there's a decent chance for all three in one location so I'm asking all three in one. Would prefer not to track three separate questions for what might be one site.